# Directive showing empty tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement directives in my app, but I can't even start with the simplest one. Can someone tell me why?

JS:

```
angular
        .module('app.admin.catalog.nutritional_facts')
        .directive('nutritionalInfo', nutritionalInfo);

function nutritionalInfo(){

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            quantity: '=',
            unit: '='
        },
        template: "<div> Hello world {{ '{{quantity.qty}} {{unit.u}}' }}</div>"  
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
 <nutritional-info quantity="{qty:4}" unit="{u:'g'}"></nutritional-info>
```

I'm somewhat new to Angular, so it is probably the simplest question ever. It only shows the empty label, it doesn't even show the Hello world. I already tried sending ints, strings and objects as attributes.

Comment: Well to start with you are declaring `NutritionalInfo` with a capital `N` which should be `nutritionalInfo`

Comment: Secondly, your object syntax is wrong. `quantity="{qty: 4}"` would be the correct way to pass an object to this attribute

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really stupid mistakes from me but corrected both and still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I've corrected your code as shown below to get your directive working as expected : 
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/7/)

**My Changes :**

1. Corrected directive name to camel case
2. Corrected the angular binding in html
3. Corrected the objects syntax that are passed to the directive.

**HTML :**

```
<nutritional-info quantity="{qty:4}" unit="{u:'g'}"></nutritional-info>
```

**Controller :**

```
angular.module('app.admin.catalog.nutritional_facts', [])
    .directive('nutritionalInfo', nutritionalInfo);

function nutritionalInfo(){

 return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        quantity: '=',
        unit: '='
    },
    template: "<div> Hello world {{quantity.qty}} {{unit.u}}</div>"  
 };
}
```

Comment: The module is declared in a different .js , and the ng-app is also included. Both js are implemented in the HTML. thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've downvoted you because you're encouraging copy-pasting the code instead of explaining *what* you changed. If you change that I'll redact the DV.

Comment: @DanPantry Sorry about that, I have added the required code first and then started adding the changes I've made.

Comment: @Sslink: I was thinking that module is not defined and made that change. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues:

- `NutritionalInfo` should be `nutritionalInfo` (camelCase). That's how Angular will know to associate that directive with the `<nutritional-info>` HTML tag. See [Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).
- You're not passing in objects correctly to the directive. `quantity="{qty=4}"` should be `quantity="{qty: 4}"`.
- You're not evaluating the expression correctly in the template. `{{ '{{quantity.qty}} {{unit.u}}' }}` can simply be `{{quantity.q}} {{unit.u}}`. [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) are interpreted like JavaScript code run on the current scope. So, you can even build expressions like `{{quantity.q.toFixed(1) + ' ' + unit.u.toUpperCase()}}` (resulting in `4.0 G`).

With all those fixes, here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o932zpa4/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app.admin.catalog.nutritional_facts">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body >

<nutritional-info quantity="{qty: 3}" unit="{u: 'g'}"></nutritional-info>

<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>

<script>

    function nutritionalInfo(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                quantity: '=',
                unit: '='
            },
            template: "<div> Hello world '{{quantity.qty}} {{unit.u}}'</div>"
        };
    }

    angular
            .module('app.admin.catalog.nutritional_facts', [])
            .directive('nutritionalInfo', nutritionalInfo);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```